# Is there a tool that checks GWT JRE emulation library violations?

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to port a Swing application to GWT.

However lots of this application classes use things that are not supported by GWT JRE emulation library such as java.util.Locale, java.text.SimpleDateFormat and much more.

Is there a tool that scans a project and spots such problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Plugin for Eclipse shows errors for things that are unsupported by GWT's JRE emulation. http://code.google.com/eclipse/

Comment: Don't suppose you know of a corresponding tool/mechanism for Intellij IDEA?

Comment: @David JRE Emulation classes checking is built-in since IntelliJ IDEA 14, probably. But check fails for automatically translated packages, classes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The GWT compiler will complain if you try to access classes in the JRE that are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

My GWT plugin does not warn until the end of  a compilation process.

I fixed this issue by the following way.

In eclipse,
Create a java project.
Remove JRE from class path.
Go to gwt-user.jar. Locate java emulation classes. The path is like that: ..super../emul/java/...
Copy them to your java project.
What we get So far, your Java project without JRE have java.lan. and etc. classes. 
This will work except com.google.gwt.lang.Array.java will be missing.
I created that array class (you can find it from internet, I couldn't locate it inside jars).
Add gwt-user and dev jars to the classpath.

Now, your own library can use only gwt java emulation and other gwt classes.
Eclipse will automatically warn you if you access a non emulated Java library.