# GWT-JRE-Emulated classes aware Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, java, emulation

Is there any way to make Eclipse (or Eclipse forks) aware of which JRE classes are or are not emulated by GWT on the client-side?

IntelliJ for example is aware of the emulated classes and warns if we use non-emulated classes.
Is it possible to have the same in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, I'm not aware of a feature like this. The Google Plugin for Eclipse performs some [project validations](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/project_validations.html). But it can not check whether the used classes are in the JRE emulation library or not.

In another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074876/is-there-a-tool-that-checks-gwt-jre-emulation-library-violations) someone made a suggestion to remove the Java library from the Eclipse project and to define a user library. Although this does not feel like a perfect solution. You d'have to split your client and server code into two Eclipse projects.

You could also use Eclipse [access rules](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/concept-access-rules.htm) feature, but you have to define those rules yourselfs...